# Parse a datetime string from amazon mechanical turk to django orm

Tags: python, datetime, django-models, mechanicalturk

Mechanical turk provides strings like this:
    'Wed Nov 03 17:14:17 PDT 2010'

Django datetime model fields require 
    YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]]

What's the right way to take in the 1st string and create the 2nd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`time.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) and [`time.strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) !

Answer (score 3):

```
t = time.strptime("Wed Nov 03 17:14:17 PDT 2010", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")  
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", t)
```